# Enforcing method order in a Python module

Tags: oop, singleton, python

What is the most Pythonic way to deal with a module in which methods must be called in a certain order?

As an example, I have an XML configuration that must be read before doing anything else because the configuration affects behavior.

The `parse_config()` must be called first with the configuration file provided.  Calling other supporting methods, like `query_data()` won't work until `parse_config()` has been called.

I first implemented this as a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to ensure that a filename for the configuration is passed at the time of initialization, but I was noticing that modules are actually singletons. It's no longer a class, but just a regular module.

What's the best way to enforce the `parse_config` being called first in a module?

It is worth noting is that the function is actually `parse_config(configfile)`.

Comment: Create a class that contains the method and let the user provide the filename as parameter to the __init__ method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the object isn't valid before it's called, then call that method in `__init__` (or use a factory function). You don't need any silly singletons, that's for sure.

Comment: It's not a class, but just a flat list of functions, one of which is `parse_config()`.  All these convenience functions are in a module together.  Does a module have it's own `__init__`?  I only know of `__init__` for classes.

Comment: @shadowland: Global state is bad. Global state that depends on magical incantations is double bad.

Comment: I second @CatPlusPlus re global state, but you can do some magic in the `__init__.py` file if you structure your module as a package. This feels like a really bad way to do things though.

Comment: Is it more preferable to just re-read the config each time it's used by a different module?  In the case of preferences, global state seemed like a good idea to me.  What are my options?

Comment: @shadowland: No, pass it along as you go, wherever it's needed. It doesn't even have to be a class, `parse_config` can return a dict or whatever, that you pass to functions that need it.

Comment: How do I keep things DRY and not have `Config('/path/to/config')` all over my code?  If I need to specify a different file later, I'd like to change it in one place.

Comment: @shadowland: Then create the object once. Making dependencies explicit is not against DRY. And it has the automatic benefit of making your code more generic.

Comment: +1 "Explicit is better than implicit" is exactly about this sort of thing. Create the object, and avoid repeating yourself by passing the object around instead of re-creating it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus  I think just making it a class and passing the instantiated object around seems like the most sane idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The model I have been using is that subsequent functions are only available as methods on the return value of previous functions, like this:

```
class Second(object):
   def two(self):
     print "two"
     return Third()

class Third(object):
   def three(self):
     print "three"

def one():
   print "one"
   return Second()

one().two().three()
```

Properly designed, this style (which I admit is not terribly Pythonic, *yet*) makes for fluent libraries to handle complex pipeline operations where later steps in the library require both the results of early calculations and fresh input from the calling function.

An interesting result is error handling.  What I've found is the best way of handling well-understood errors in pipeline steps is having a blank Error class that supposedly can handle every function in the pipeline (except initial one) but those functions (except possibly terminal ones) return only `self`:

```
class Error(object):
   def two(self, *args):
      print "two not done because of earlier errors"
      return self
   def three(self, *args):
      print "three not done because of earlier errors"

class Second(object):
   def two(self, arg):
     if arg == 2:
       print "two"
       return Third()
     else:
       print "two cannot be done"
       return Error()

class Third(object):
   def three(self):
     print "three"

def one(arg):
   if arg == 1:
      print "one"
      return Second()
   else:
      print "one cannot be done"
      return Error()

one(1).two(-1).three()
```

In your example, you'd have the Parser class, which would have almost nothing but a `configure` function that returned an instance of a ConfiguredParser class, which would do all the thing that only a properly configured parser could do.  This gives you access to such things as multiple configurations and handling failed attempts at configuration.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I haven't thought of something like that.  It feels a lot like a dictionary in which the top returns a class:  `one[0].two()`

Comment: @shadowland -- an advantage of this approach is that it works *even better* in statically-typed languages.  A dictionary approach would fall apart there.

Comment: +1, best answer.  Though as someone who doesn't have a great handle on `Pythonic`, I'd like to know why you think (or have been convinced to think) that this is un-`Pythonic`.

Comment: @MattFenwick -- I don't know if it's un-Pythonic, just that I haven't seen much -- well, any -- Python code written this way.  It's something I picked up from Scala.

Answer (score 1):

As [Cat Plus Plus said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906187/enforcing-method-order-in-a-python-module/7906219#7906219) in other words, wrap the behaviour/functions up in a class and put all the required setup in the `__init__` method.

You might complain that the functions don't seem like they naturally belong together in an object and, hence, this is bad OO design.  If that's the case, think of your class/object as a form of name-spacing.  It's much cleaner and more flexible than trying to enforce function calling order somehow or using singletons.

Comment: Agree. Wrap it up in a class. Maintain a simple state machine within the class. Calling query_data() before parse_config() will throw a "Must Parse Data First" exception.

Comment: I was trying to keep things DRY.  I was concerned about having (assuming the class is called `Config`) `Config('/path/to/config')` in many different locations in the code.

Comment: Well, if you are going to be reusing the same config and data throughout your entire program (at least for now), make the class as we suggested and then create a single instance of it that you import into the rest of your code.  It'll be a singleton, but at least you then have the ability to change that easily in the future if you need.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to how friendly you want your error messages to be if a function is called before it is configured.

Least friendly is to do nothing extra, and let the functions fail noisily with `AttributeError`s, `IndexError`s, etc.

Most friendly would be having stub functions that raise an informative exception, such as a custom `ConfigError:  configuration not initialized`.  When the `ConfigParser()` function is called it can then replace the stub functions with real functions.

Something like this:

#### File *config.py*

```
class ConfigError(Exception):
    "configuration errors"

def query_data():
    raise ConfigError("parse_config() has not been called")

def _query_data():
    do_actual_work()

def parse_config(config_file):
    load_file(config_file)
    if failure:
        raise ConfigError("bad file")
    all_objects = globals()
    for name in ('query_data', ):
        working_func = all_objects['_'+name]
        all_objects[name] = working_func
```

If you have very many functions you can add decorators to keep track of the function names, but that's an answer for a different question.  ;)

Okay,  I couldn't resist -- here is the decorator version, which makes my solution much easier to actually implement:

```
class ConfigError(Exception):
    "various configuration errors"

class NeedsConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, module_namespace):
        self._namespace = module_namespace
        self._functions = dict()
    def __call__(self, func):
        self._functions[func.__name__] = func
        return self._stub
    @staticmethod
    def _stub(*args, **kwargs):
        raise ConfigError("parseconfig() needs to be called first")
    def go_live(self):
        for name, func in self._functions.items():
            self._namespace[name] = func
```

And a sample run:

```
needs_parseconfig = NeedsConfig(globals())

@needs_parseconfig
def query_data():
    print "got some data!"

@needs_parseconfig
def set_data():
    print "set the data!"

def okay():
    print "Okay!"

def parse_config(somefile):
    needs_parseconfig.go_live()

try:
    query_data()
except ConfigError, e:
    print e

try:
    set_data()
except ConfigError, e:
    print e

try:
    okay()
except:
    print "this shouldn't happen!"
    raise

parse_config('config_file')
query_data()
set_data()
okay()
```

And the results:

```
parseconfig() needs to be called first
parseconfig() needs to be called first
Okay!
got some data!
set the data!
Okay!
```

As you can see, the decorator works by remembering the functions it decorates, and instead of returning a decorated function it returns a simple stub that raises a `ConfigError` if it is ever called.  When the `parse_config()` routine is called, it needs to call the `go_live()` method which will then replace all the error raising stubs with the actual remembered functions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple requirement that a module needs to be "configured" before it is used is best handled by a class which does the "configuration" in the `__init__` method, as in the currently-accepted answer. Other module functions become methods of the class. *There is no benefit in trying to make a singleton ... the caller may well want to have two or more differently-configured gadgets operating simultaneously.*

Moving on from that to a more complicated requirement, such as a temporal ordering of the methods:

This can be handled in a quite general fashion by maintaining state in attributes of the object, as is usually done in any OOPable language. Each method that has prerequisites must check that those prequisites are satisfied.

Poking in replacement methods is an obfuscation on a par with the [COBOL ALTER verb](http://www.tonymarston.net/cobol/cobolstandards.html#alter), and made worse by using decorators -- it just wouldn't/shouldn't get past code review.

Comment: I agree a class is the best way to handle this; keep in mind, though, that modules, like classes, are just objects.

Comment: Going the class route it is still possible to use the replacement method method, although not with `__xxx__` methods as they are always looked up in the class.  While not a technique that should be used often, it can be helpful from time to time, much like `from ... import *` should not be used often, but is helpful from time to time.

Answer (score -1):

A module doesn't do anything it isn't told to do so put your function calls at the bottom of the module so that when you import it, things get ran in the order you specify:

### test.py

```
import testmod
```

### testmod.py

```
def fun1():
    print('fun1')

def fun2():
    print('fun2')

fun1()
fun2()
```

When you run test.py, you'll see fun1 is ran before fun2:

```
python test.py 
fun1
fun2
```

Comment: But like the guys mentioned above, global state is bad but sometimes you need to initialize or do something before your module can be useful.

Comment: This doesn't work because `parse_config(configfile)` takes an argument that's provided to it.  I could probably do as you suggest using some sane default and then allow the user to call parse_config again if the default configuration location isn't sufficient.