# I need an object to do anything

Tags: python

Or at least, to pretend to do anything.

```
>>> three = Three()
>>> three.value()
3
>>> three.sqrt()
3
>>> three.close()
3
>>> three.someRandomFunctionWithMadeUpParameters("hello, world", math.PI, True)
3
>>> three.stopSayingThreeDamnIt()
3
```

Is it possible to implement class `Three` in Python 2.6 ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @RussellBorogove -- I want to build a generic pipeline-error object as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906187/enforcing-method-order-in-a-python-module/7906457#7906457).   It would return `self` in real life, not 3. Your wife isn't named Mimsy, is she?

Comment: In this case you might rather want to create a decorator that throws away the original return value (or stores it somewhere) and returns `self` instead. `__getattr__` only works for things that don't exist and while using `__getattribute__` would do the job, you'd still have to call a real function to perform something - using a decorator is clearly cleaner.

Comment: I *need* it to work only for things that don't exist.  At the very end of the process, I need to ask, "Well, how'd it go?" and at that point, it has to stop saying "self, self, self" and say, "Sorry, boss, things went pear-shape about four steps back..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Three(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda *args, **kw: 3
```

Comment: Make 3 a 4 and there you have an ultimate random number generator!

Answer (score 1):

```
class MetaThree(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return '3'
    def __getattr__(cls,key):
        return Three

class Three(object):
    __metaclass__=MetaThree
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        pass
    def __call__(self):
        return Three
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return Three
    def __repr__(self):
        return '3'

three=Three()
print(three.value())
# 3
print(three.someRandomFunc('hello'))
# 3
print(three.someRandomFunc)
# 3
print(three.someRandomFunc.foo.bar)
# 3
print(three()()())
# 3
```