# How to represent protected methods in Python classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, protected

Reading [this question on method ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10289461/1079110), I thought about where to put protected methods and whether they should be private `_method(self)` or public `method(self)` in Python. I know that Python doesn't provide a language feature for protected methods.

- **Private:** By convention, attributes starting with an underscore are private. They can still normally be accessed from the outside but should not. Starting protected methods with an underscore feels weird since it is unclear that the subclass actually overrides the method rather than declaring its own implementation detail.
- **Public:** Without the underscore, it is more likely that someone would take a look at the base class to see whether the method is already there. Thus this is nicer for people who subclass. However, people who want to use the subclass don't know that the method is just an implementation detail and might try to call it from the outside.

What is the preferred way to define protected methods in Python?

Comment: Also see [Why are Python's 'private' methods not actually private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private) As Guido said: "We're all consenting adults here".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use names starting with a single underscore.

A protected method is a *implementation detail* that you want to share with subclasses, so such methods are not part of the public API. Anything not part of the public API is best named with an initial underscore.

In other words, 'protected' should be treated just the same as 'private'. Protected methods only need to exist in a language with a strict privacy model where making such implementation details private would preclude sharing such methods with subclasses. Python has no such problem.

Whatever you do, do **not** use a leading *double* underscore; such names are considered *class private* and are namespaced to the class that defines them (they are renamed by the compiler by prefixing `_ClassName` in front), to ensure that subclasses don't accidentally overwrite them.